# Rejecting calls using MODIFY_PHONE_STATE or other method

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I want to reject incoming calling on Gingerbread and ice cream sandwich but `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` doesn't work. How should I use it?

Is there another way to reject incoming calls?

Comment: Unfortunately some random #&!£head @ Google changed the permissions for MODIFY_PHONE_STATE without any good reason - so - no, you can't.

Comment: some app on market can reject incoming call on Gingerbread . I think we have another way